# REST endpoints alongside regular Browser endpoints

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm making a web app using `Spring Boot` and `Spring Security` 
I have some normal endpoints that work from the browser displaying normal web pages and also some `REST` endpoints for desktop application to consume.
 But when I applied `Spring Security` every thing works fine for the normal endpoints but when testing the `REST APIs` on postman I keep getting the login form as if I'm using the browser which is expected cause in security configuration all `URLs` should be authenticated 
After searching I found that all tutorials are making `REST` security configs by disabling the `csrf` and `login forms` 
Someone suggested to separate into two projects, but in my case they are using the same `DB` and services only different controllers, as I'm new to the Spring world what is the best approach should I go with while keeping every thing simple?

Comment: Please show you code so that community can help.

Comment: just need suggestions not having errors here

Comment: You should keep it in 1 project. There is no need for separate project as that makes things difficult as you are new in Spring

Comment: Ok what about the security configurations ?

Answer (score 0):

When configuring HttpSecurity, consider using ant matchers to filter out which resources should have authorised access. e. g.:

```
 http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/xxx/xxx").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/yyy/**").authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable();
```

Comment: doesn't this gonna disable the csrf for the browser end points ?